# Using SQL 'UPDATE', 'SET', 'AND' in R

Tags: sql, r, sql-update

I have written a Query that pulls individual customer accounts and purchases. After executing the query and studying the data I noticed that some individual accounts with the same product category display different account open dates. I need to update my generated query table to set those individual accounts with the same product category to the original open date or the earliest date opened (minimum date). An example:

```
Account#   Product.Cat    Open.Date 
15672       D             08/14/2015
15672       D             08/14/2015
15672       D             03/14/2016
```

In this example I need to update the table so that the third row's Open.Date is equal to the earliest open date which is 08/14/2015.

From my research I initially thought I would have to delete those individual entries if they have a date that is not equal to the earliest open date, but I now believe that I can use a combination of UPDATE, SET, WHERE and AND statements. My problem is that this Query is written in R, and when I run my query it produces nothing and doesn't give me an error statement.  My code is below, and up to the point where you see the gap and the UPDATE function my code worked.

```
q1<- sqlQuery(ch,paste("SELECT 
lic.t_b_z_act__AC_NAME,
lic.t_b_z_act_AC_ACCT_NBR,
lic.t_b_z_act_A_PROD_CAT,
lic.t_b_z_act_A_PROD_TYP,
lic.t_b_z_act_A_OPEN_DTE,
lic.t_b_z_act_PRCS_DTE,
lic.t_b_x_bal_BL_ACCT_NBR,
lic.t_b_x_bal_PRCS_DTE,
lic.t_b_x_bal_BL_BAL
       FROM lic.t_b_z_act
       Left JOIN lic.t_b_x_bal 
       ON lic.t_b_x_bal_BL_ACCT_NBR = lic.t_b_z_act_AC_ACCT_NBR and lic.t_b_x_bal_PRCS_DTE = lic.t_b_z_act_PRCS_DTE 
       WHERE AC_Dep_CAT<>'K'AND AC_Dep_CAT<>'C' AND AC_OPEN_DTE>'2014-10-30'

       UPDATE t_b_a_act
       SET AC_Open_DTE = MIN(AC_OPEN_DTE)
       WHERE AC_NAME = AC_NAME AND AC_PROD_CAT=AC_PROD_CAT AND AC_OPEN_DTE>MIN(AC_OPEN_DTE);

          "))
```

Answer (score 0):

using `data.table`

**sample data**

```
dt <- fread("Account#   Product.Cat    Open.Date 
15672       D             08/14/2015
15672       D             08/14/2015
15672       D             03/14/2016")
```

**code**

```
#set keys for sorting    
setkey(dt, Product.Cat, Open.Date)
#set Open.Date by reference to the first Open.Date of each group
#whch is the earliest, because it is sorted by keys
dt[, Open.Date := Open.Date[1], by = .(Product.Cat)][]
```

**output**

```
   Account# Product.Cat  Open.Date
1:    15672           D 03/14/2016
2:    15672           D 03/14/2016
3:    15672           D 03/14/2016
```

Comment: This actually does not work because it does not account for different account #s.

Comment: There are actually no different accounts in your sample data. But if there would be, you could just add them in the `by=`-argument for grouping.